# Using form select option value to access json array in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

friends. I'm using 2 form select fields to access some json arrays. The first select option is the parent array, and the second is the child array.

I've got in logging in the console just fine, so I think I might just be messing up the notation? But I'm not sure. I'm new to working with JSON.

In the code below, quoteValue is coming up undefined.

```
$('select#input_56_4').on('change', function () {
   var loanValue = $('select#input_56_4 option:selected').val();
   var stateValue = $('select#input_56_3 option:selected').val();
   console.log(stateValue + ' ' + loanValue);

   var quoteValue = data[stateValue].loanValue;
   console.log('newValue = ' + quoteValue);
   document.getElementById("testjson").innerHTML = quoteValue;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to not mix bracket and dot notation.

```
var quoteValue = data[stateValue][loanValue];
```

Is how that should look / work.